# Accessing SharePoint using Microsoft Graph through Office Add-in (Word JS)

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I have developed an Office.js Word add-in and I am using the SSO feature as described [here](https://github.com/officedev/office-add-in-aspnet-sso). It uses the `Office.Auth interface` method `getAccessTokenAsync`, shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.auth?view=word-js-1.3). This works as described, but the issue comes when I try to use more scopes to access SharePoint using Microsoft Graph.

**TL;DR**
I am unable to successfully make Microsoft Graph calls to access SharePoint with the token generated from the Office.Auth interface `getAccessTokenAsync` method.

**Full Description**

I have done the following:

1. Added the `Sites.ReadWrite.All` and `Sites.Manage.All` permissions in
   the Azure AD app registration.
2. Added the additional scopes in the Word Add-in manifest.

   ```
   <WebApplicationInfo>
     <Id>$application_GUID here$</Id>
     <Resource>api://localhost:44355/$application_GUID here$</Resource>
     <Scopes>
         <Scope>Files.Read.All</Scope>
         <Scope>Sites.ReadWrite.All</Scope>
         <Scope>Sites.Manage.All</Scope>
         <Scope>offline_access</Scope>
         <Scope>openid</Scope>
         <Scope>profile</Scope>
     </Scopes>
   </WebApplicationInfo>
   ```
3. Confirmed using Graph Explorer that I can make the SharePoint Graph
   calls, as my user.

   ```
   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}
   ```
4. Added the additional scopes in the `Authorize` method for when the user is not logged into Word, as described [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO/blob/master/src/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO-WebAPI/Controllers/AzureADAuthController.cs).

   ```
   ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder clientBuilder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Settings.AzureADClientId);
   clientBuilder.WithClientSecret(Settings.AzureADClientSecret);
   clientBuilder.WithRedirectUri(loginRedirectUri.ToString());
   clientBuilder.WithAuthority(Settings.AzureADAuthority);

   ConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = (ConfidentialClientApplication) clientBuilder.Build();
   string[] graphScopes = { "Files.Read.All", "User.Read", "Sites.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.Manage.All" };

   // Get and save the token.
   var authResultBuilder = clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
       graphScopes,
       Request.Params["code"] // The auth 'code' parameter from the Azure redirect.
   );

   try
   {
       var authResult = await authResultBuilder.ExecuteAsync();
       ViewBag.AccessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       ViewBag.Error = e.Message;
   }

   return View();
   ```

**What Works**
When the user is not logged into Word and has to call the `Authorize` method, I am able to use the returned token to successfully make my Graph calls.

**What does not Work**
When the user is already logged into Word and the add-in JS generates the token using the `getAccessTokenAsync` method, I get 'Unauthorized' when trying to make the same Graph calls using the returned

**Question**
Is there something extra I need to do for the Office JS `getAccessTokenAsync` method to return an authorized token for use with my Graph calls to SharePoint?

**Edit Post Further Investigation**
I used [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to decode the tokens received.

1. With the older `getAccessTokenAsync` method when logged in
   (*scenario that does not work*), I get a token containing the
   following:

```
{
  "aud": $application_GUID$,
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenant_GUID$/v2.0",
  "iat": ...,
  "nbf": ...,
  "exp": ...,
  "aio": ...,
  "azp": ...,
  "azpacr": "0",
  "name": $user_full_name$,
  "oid": $GUID$,
  "preferred_username": $user_email$,
  "scp": "access_as_user",
  "sub": ...,
  "tid": $tenant_GUID$,
  "uti": ...,
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

2. With the newer `getAccessToken` method, both when logged
   in and prompted to log in, (*scenarios that also do not work*), I
   get a token containing the same as above.
3. With the older
   `getAccessTokenAsync` method, when prompted to log in and taken to
   the`AzureADAuthController`, (*scenario that does work!*), I get a
   token containing the following:

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/$tenant_GUID$/",
  "iat": ...,
  "nbf": ...,
  "exp": ...,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": ...,
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO",
  "appid": $application_GUID$,
  "appidacr": "1",
  "deviceid": $GUID$,
  "family_name": $user_last_name$,
  "given_name": $user_first_name$,
  "ipaddr": ...,
  "name": $user_full_name$,
  "oid": $GUID$,
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": ...,
  "scp": "Files.Read.All openid profile Sites.Manage.All Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read email",
  "sub": ...,
  "tid": $tenant_GUID$,
  "unique_name": $user_email$,
  "upn": $user_email$,
  "uti": ...,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": ...
  },
  "xms_tcdt": ...
}
```

Notice the difference in scopes, where the latter, older version has fully listed scopes, and I am able to authorize this way.

What could explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but too long to put in a comment:

That sample changed recently to use the new `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken`. You seem to be using an older version that uses `Office.auth.getAccessTokenAsync`. That should still work, but it was a preview API and may stop working at some point. Consider cloning the newer version. But wait a few days. I'm about to push some fixes to the new version.

Check to see if you've also added the new scopes to the `graphScopes` array in the Login action method. (In addition to adding them to the Authorize action method as you've already done.)

Exactly which HTTP call is returning the "Unauthorized"?

What error is being retuned from `getAccessToken` (or `getAccessTokenAsync`)? It usually has a 13xxx number.

**UPDATE 12/19/19:**

Based on your description in your comment "To clarify...", it looks like you are including the token that you get from `getAccessToken` in your call to MS Graph. This will not work. That token is a "bootstrap token". It gives Office access to your add-in's web app. The web app then needs to use the **On Behalf Of Flow** to swap that token for a token that gives the web app access to MS Graph. You then include this *second token* as the **Authorization** header in the call to Graph. The sample that you linked to in the first sentence of your question does that. Please also see these articles:

[Enable SSO in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins)

[Authorize to Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph)

Finally, be sure that there is a blank space between the string "Bearer" and the token in the Authorization header.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I have used the `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken` and updated the `graphScopes` array in the Login action method, but I still get 'Unauthorized' for the Graph call mentioned above to get a SharePoint List Item `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}`. I successfully get a token with `getAccessToken ` but I'm unable to use it for the Graph call.

Comment: Use the Fiddler tool to see the Request for that call. Is the access token in the Authorization header? Also look at the Response in Fiddler. There may be more info about the error.

Comment: I updated the question after using https://jwt.io/ to decode the tokens received. I'm hoping this could provide further clarification on the issue.

Comment: On 2nd thought, just stop using `getAccessTokenAsync`. I think that's just adding an unnecessary layer of confusion. `getAccessToken` is what should be used going forward. Please use Fiddler as suggested. (FYI:  If `AzureADAuthController` is running, then that means that the SSO system failed and branched to the fallback system. Look for `dialogFallback` in this file https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO/blob/master/Complete/Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO-WebAPI/Scripts/HomeES6.js.]

Comment: I understand that I should use `getAccessToken` instead but it is still the case that the token provided by the fallback system using `AzureADAuthController` is the only one that allows me to use Graph successfully to access SharePoint. The token provided by all other SSO methods still gives me 'Unauthorized' when trying to use Graph to access SharePoint. I was trying to highlight the differences in the tokens generated to see if there was something missing from the token generated by the SSO system.

Comment: The token you are getting from the fallback system is a ver 1.0 AAD token. SSO gets a ver 2.0 token. You'll see those values near the end of the two tokens. I can't tell from the info that you've provided where you are seeing this "Unauthorized" error. Please use the debugger and Fiddler to pinpoint where the code first branches to an error.

Comment: To clarify what's happening, here are my steps:   
1. Use `getAccessToken` to get the token 
2. Using the given token I make a call such as this: `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);  var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}"; HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url);`
3. `response.StatusCode` then equals 'Unauthorized.'

Comment: Using Fiddler, I do see the token in the Authorization header. It says "Authorization Header is present", and I see the token. But the error is   
`"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
 "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."`

Comment: However, when taking the exact same steps using the token provided by the fallback method the `response.StatusCode` then equals 'OK.'

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Using the second token provided by the On Behalf Of Flow is what I was missing.